# Building Flex component inside SBT

Tags: apache-flex, scala, sbt

We are using SBT for our Lift project. One of the modules is Flex based and we would like to integrate its build with rest of the project. Is there a way for the same ? I couldn't find much information on the net.

We are using 0.11.0 version for SBT

Best Regards
Narinder

Comment: There is a way to call the mxmlc compiler with Ant. I believe you can do the same with SBT. You'll probably have to research building flex applicatinos with mxmlc.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=apparch_08.html

Comment: Hi Anton, We have mxmlc command. Currently we are building flex component through a shell script. We don't know how to call this script / or better integrate it through SBT.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sbt 0.11.0 [tasks](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks) running mxmlc as an [external](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Process) process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Ant to fork new process of mxmlc. Just call [Flex compiler API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/compilerAPI_flex3.pdf) in your `project/Build.scala`, which is much faster, because it avoids JRE's slow startup.